# Are we migrating too readily?

Tags: discussion

For example, this question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22864/lambda-calculus-difference-between-contexts-and-evaluation-contexts had two very thorough research-level answers, and was migrated to CS.SE.

Comment: I was invited to migrate this question by the CS mods, and I took them up on it.  I agree I might have jumped the gun.  Is this *question* really research level?

Comment: I think it's pretty similar to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/why-is-cnf-used-for-sat-and-not-dnf/1413#1413 in "research level". It would be surprising for anyone to discuss the question outside of a graduate course.

Comment: Also, I might be a little more reluctant about "Theory B" questions, and PL in particular, because we don't have enough of those on cstheory.

Comment: Upon further reflection, you are right -- I am sorry for my mistake.  Unfortunately, I don't believe my action is reversible.  (It would be great if we had a mod from "Theory B".)

Comment: I don't think it's a big issue for this question. As for Theory B mods, any of these people would be good choices: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87/pl-programming-languages

Comment: @Sam, I don't have an opinion about the question. I just wanted to point two small points: 1. the question you link to as example is from 2010 and beta phase of the site and might not be received as well if it was posted today. 2. I would guess that Gilles was the [cs.se] mod who suggested the migration, he is one of the people who have answered the question and he is from theory B.

Comment: Yes, @Kaveh is correct about the history.  I still think I probably migrated too early.

Comment: ah, innocent question cutting to core of this groups mass personality/psychology. seems an attitude around here that serious research questions cannot be asked by amateurs, so that is some of the evaluation that is being (behind-the-scenes) applied. to me that works against the openess of the site & cs.se now exceeds tcs.se in total questions. (but many here would say _so what_ to that). there are some deep questions asked by amateurs and imho [another recent one wrt lambda calculus](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/) (not migrated but some suggested it) is another example

Comment: @vzn, I would have been sad had that question been migrated, since it's definitely research level _and_ I learned something reading the answers.

Comment: anyway as much as ppl _asking_ the questions might value them, they are not typically that highly valued in the stackexchange system... so any much sensitivity to individual questions does not really fit with the stackexchange model. agreed the specific question raised above was borderline yet the mods need room to breathe... lets not pretend that theres not a big subjective aspect to IDing on-topic questions & many experts can disagree on "edge cases" (& have in past)... just wish _benefit of doubt_ was more given to _questioners_ than the _mods_... but that is se culture in general _not to!_

Comment: We used to have a theory B mod when Dave was a mod :). In general (and I've been toying with phrasing a meta question about this) I think that now that we're long past the beta stage, we might consider shedding some of our insecurity about 'research level or not'.

Comment: @Suresh, I don't think it has anything to do with "insecurity". Here is the question: do you regularly visit [cs.se]? Most of us don't and there is a very good reason why we visit cstheory regularly but visit [cs.se] only from time to time. The scope has already extended enough and I for one would be strongly against dropping the fact that the questions on cstheory should be related to research.

Comment: I certainly don't visit CS.SE much, that's why I'd like there to be more of the things I'm interested in in cstheory. To do that, we'd need more "Theory B", which I think could be helped by being more forgiving of "research level" in that area.

The other improvement I'd like is to see more less-theory research here -- I don't think that PL theory splits that neatly from PL implementation etc in the academic community, for example.

But the community has been pretty against the latter in the past.

Comment: @Sam, I would also like more theory B questions but not theory B questions which are at the level of standard undergrad textbooks. The scope has been extended a number of times and as I said above I for one would be strongly against extending it so much that the site is not about research. I personally want (And that was the original intention) to have a TCS version of [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.com), not a TCS version of [math.se].

Comment: [continued] The scope of cstheory is theoretical computer science but theory here is meant to be interpreted broadly, e.g. being mathematically rigorous, see [help/on-topic]. [cs.se]'s scope is wider and if one is interested in more general question then the natural thing to do is to start visiting [cs.se] in place of duplicating their scope on csthoery. I think many users who know about [cs.se] and don't like to visit it would object to extending the scope of csthoery so much that it becomes a duplicate of [cs.se]. (I personally visit [cs.se] but less often and not during busy periods).

Comment: @Kaveh, first, no $\lambda$-calculus at all appears in "standard undergrad textbooks". Second, I also want something like MathOverflow for the work I do, but in my work, the TCS aspects do not so neatly separate from the non-TCS aspects. CS.SE is clearly not the solution -- it's audience is not research-level.

Comment: @Sam, I am not talking about any particular questions, I don't consider myself an expert to express opinion (though I think programming language courses now a days do touch on lambda calculus when discussing functional programming), but my point was general. If you feel some question is suitable on cstheory and it gets closed you can ask for its reopening on meta (it is a draw back of migration that it cannot be easily undone). That doesn't need a change in scope, you only have to convince other theory B users that the question is suitable in the current scope

Comment: which as far as I understand essentially means it is above the level of typical undergraduate textbook exercise and a good undergraduate who have studied the topic cannot answer the question. 
Regarding the audience of [cs.se], what would keep the audience of cstheory mainly researchers if we duplicate the scope of [cs.se]? Note that several people have expressed strong opinion against judging questions based on who asks them. It may not happen in a month but after sometime the audience of cstheory will also become not "research level".

Comment: re scope, mod suresh [proposed a highly-supported expansion](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/on-modifying-our-scope-a-proposal) over 1½ yr ago. respectfully suggest a mod reinitiate/revisit this discussion in new post & also makes sense to reevaulate with 2/3 new mods. maybe some analysis, did the scope expand as recommended/conensus/generally agreed since that post? scope is regulated via & can only basically expand through mass voting patterns and even mods cannot dictate voting... there is also some reason to suspect that many users do not pay attn to meta at all...!

Comment: @Kaveh, I don't know what causes you to think I want cstheory to become like CS.SE. I think I've said repeatedly that I don't want that. Instead, I've made two suggestions.  That we be more lenient about closing/migrating in areas where there isn't a big audience on cstheory today (basically anything outside of algorithms/theory of computation). And also that we we should broaden cstheory to research-level aspects of CS somewhat beyond what it's currently about. The second is obviously controversial, and I don't expect it to happen, though.

Comment: @Sam, I just want people to think about the consequences of extending the scope. If you agree that we should not allow questions at the level of typical undergrad textbook exercise then we agree.

Comment: The other point I am trying to make is that _the scope is already permissive of the questions you want_. We have extended the scope a number of times, e.g. see vzn's link, it is already quite permissive. You can point people to that discussion if you feel a question fits the scope but is being closed/migrated.

Comment: @Lev, I don't think it is a matter of time, there is no simple solution for migration disagreements: for almost any good question that you may consider migrating to [cs.se] there is potentially someone who would want to keep it here even if the question had 4 close votes, that is why I stopped migrating.

Comment: se migration mechanisms are awkward for many incl mods... a possible compromise wrt the original issue is not to migrate _quickly_ for borderline cases giving more benefit of doubt to askers choice... mods can even migrate _after_ some answers have materialized on tcs.se! (which presumably questioner & others would not object to.) but note there are various questions that dont get answered on tcs.se even after some time... anyway all answers tend to materialize within 1-2 days if ever...

Comment: From the perspective of a [cs.SE] mod: if [cstheory.SE] drops the "research level" part of their scope, there is no reason to keep the site; it already *is* a proper subset in scope of [cs.SE] and all that sets is apart is the advanced level.

Answer (score 4):

I'm partly at fault with this, since I tend to suggest migration for theory B questions about $\lambda$-calculus which I believe to be simple/well-known.

I agree we should strive to be easier on these questions though: there's not much theory B going on at undergraduate levels, and there aren't many high-profile open questions, so there are a number of motivated, and "non-cranky" amateurs (or at least not researchers in those fields) out there, with few resources to learn.

Of course there are some "are these terms $\alpha$-equal?" questions, but for anything above that, I think we should be more tolerant of $\lambda$-calculus and Logic and Computation-style questions.

That said, specific questions about programing in Coq or Agda (or other ITPs) should be off-topic here and at CS.se.

Comment: "...I tend to migrate..." mods migrate. maybe you mean you _flag_ to migrate? even in that case its still their decision.

Comment: Yes I meant suggest migration one way or another.